# How is a running IntentService managed after the app process is killed

Tags: android, xamarin, intentservice

Just trying to clarify my understanding of how an `IntentService` is managed by the OS once *terminating* states have been reached. By *terminating*, I mean when the current activity is destroyed or the app process is killed, as per the following documentation:
https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/activity-lifecycle

Given the comment

> Also, an IntentService isn't affected by most user interface lifecycle events, so it continues to run in circumstances that would shut down an AsyncTask

at https://developer.android.com/training/run-background-service/create-service;

I feel as if:
1) A started `IntentService` is unaffected by the activity lifecycle. Is this correct?

2) If (1) is true, will it continue to run indefinitely even after a terminating state is reached, up to some point that it either stops itself or the OS decides to stop it?

In my particular situation, I'm using an `IntentService` during app startup to query APIs, grab content, and then add a new (landing) `Page` to the Xamarin.Forms navigation stack (this would be equivalent to starting a new activity).
This leads me to my next question...

3) What happens if the app is already in a terminated state when it comes time to the `IntentService` creating a new Activity? Surely the Activity can't be added to the navigation stack as it no longer exists once the app is terminated?

Comment: Service is the base class for IntentService and it subject to the same background limitations as a "normal" service  https://developer.android.com/preview/features/background.html Will it continue running indefinitely, no, it uses a separate thread, but the process owner is the application, so if the process is killed, everything it owns is killed.

Comment: @SushiHangover Thanks. "the process owner is the application, so if the process is killed, everything it owns is killed". Where is this documented?

Comment: In the Android Application Lifecycle docs (just search for it), an application is created  in its own process (normally, there are exceptions...) and always exists when any code of your app is running (i.e. There is always a valid Android.App.Application.Context), if the OS kills the process/app (via its own accord; OOM, time violations, message looper deadlock, etc.. or via an user-based action), everything that is attached to/owned by that application context is also terminated.

Answer (score 1):

1. Yes, a started `IntentService` is unaffected by the Activity Lifecycle. Actually, all Services outside of bound Services are unaffected by the Activity Lifecycle.
2. An `IntentService` will continue until it reaches completion of it's work, the application is destroyed, or if the System decides to kill the `Service` due to the changes in the Android 8.0 background Service rules.
3. Your use of terminated state is too broad... If the Application is already terminated, then nothing will happen because the `IntentService` would have been terminated already too. If it's the `Activity` that launched the `IntentService` that was terminated, then nothing happens, since by default, an `IntentService` has nothing to do with Activities, even if it's the one that started it.

For the last question, it really depends on how you choose to communicate the result of `IntentService` to an `Activity`.

- If you're using a `BroadcastReceiver`, then nothing will happen because an `IntentService` will fire the broadcast without any problems, but the `Activity` won't be able to receive the results since it's terminated.
- But if you're simply creating a new `Activity`, then you can simply use `startActivity()` with the result data added to the Intent. Though, I doubt the user will be happy to see an `Activity` suddenly open on the screen when they're no longer in your app. Starting a new `Activity` has nothing to do with a previous `Activity`, since any instance of a `Context` can start an `Activity`.

Honestly, based on your question, it sounds like you're very concerned with an `IntentService` and it's connection with the `Activity` that started it. If that's the case, you really shouldn't be using an `IntentService`, since that's not really it's purpose. It's not meant to have a connection with an `Activity`. It's simply meant to do work and finish.

Instead, a bound `Service` would be a better option since it has a direct connection with the `Activity` that started it.

Comment: Thanks Jackey. That does give me a slightly better understanding. I actually don't care at all about the `Activity` that started my `IntentService`, rather the `Activity` that my `IntentService` _will_ start once it's done all its processing. Like you say, an `IntentService` can in fact cause an `Activity` to suddenly appear; but the actual code that the `IntentService` invokes to start this new `Activity` existed in the previous `Activity` that is now terminated, so how is that even possible?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by the "actual code that the `IntentService` invokes to start this new `Activity` existed in the previous `Activity` that is now terminated". Are you talking about `startActivity()`? `startActivity()` isn't a method that belongs to an `Activity`, instead it belongs to it's parent class `Context`. `Service` is also a child of `Context`, so it's child `IntentService` is also a child of `Context`. This gives `IntentService` the ability to directly use `startActivity()`.

Comment: Within `OnHandleIntent`, I'm doing `await Task.Run(someDelegate)`. `someDelegate ` is passed into my `IntentService` as an argument and is a reference to a lambda (say) within the previous `Activity` which looks something like `() => {//Query APIs, grab content, start LandingPageActivity}`.

Comment: Ok I think I can ask a more specific question. As long as the previous `Activity` is anywhere up to the stopped state, there's no problem; a new `Activity` can be created from the previous `Activity`. If on the other hand, the app's process is killed, then there isn't a problem either since the `IntentService` will be killed as well. Is my understanding correct thus far? Hope so. The grey area in my head is what happens when the previous `Activity` goes to the destroyed state...what happens to the lambda inside it that the `IntentService` was executing?